# Using a smarty array in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

I am trying to use smarty in javascript.

Here is my complete code of the .php and .tpl :

.Php

```
<?php

$_CRUMBS->Add("User false logs", "/users/user false logs/");


$ufl = $_DB->queryRaw("SELECT `user_id` ,`firstname`,`lastname` FROM `employees`");

while ($row = $ufl->next_assoc()) {
$results[] = $row;
}

$smarty->assign("ufl",$results);
$smarty->TDisplay("users/backend_users.tpl", "MDPI Backend | Backend Users", "general-content.tpl");

?>
```

.tpl

```
<h1>Create Backend Users</h1>



<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        {foreach from=$ufl item=uflItem}
            <tr>
                <td>{$uflItem['firstname']}</td>
            </tr>
    {/foreach}
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>


<div class="demo">
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->
```

But I have errors there. I have tryed wit literal but nothing changed. Thank you.

Comment: Smarty is not for javascript. Smarty is for PHP. Don't mix concerns :(

Comment: items in array should be separated by commas and wrapped in quotes, since they are strings.

Comment: I am a novice in PHP, smarty and Javascript developping. My goal here is o create an autocomplete box with an smarty array named $ufl. The vorking example is taken form http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/ but my goal is to usee the smarty variable instead of static array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely will have errors here, as you're using `{` and `}`, which are reserved characters in smarty.  Change them to `{ldelim}` and `{rdelim}`.  Also, dereferencing an array in smarty has different syntax: one dot.  I'm not too sure why you're putting `<tr>` and `<td>` around the items, but you know better.  You may have further troubles because your autocomplete options have line-breaks in them, so use {strip} to solve this.

Try this code instead:

```
<script>
$(function() {ldelim}
    var availableTags = [
        {foreach from=$ufl item=uflItem name=uflloop}{strip}
            '<tr>
                <td>{$uflItem.firstname|escape:'quotes'}</td>
            </tr>'
            {if !$smarty.foreach.uflloop.last},{/if}
    {/strip}{/foreach}
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({ldelim}
        source: availableTags
    {rdelim});
{rdelim});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Aleks, may be I forgot to mention that I am trying to use this in a .tpl file. When I am trying your  code, I am getting also some errors like Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Missing semicolon
 - Syntax error on tokens, delete these

Comment: @Ana Well, that would be caused by javascript syntax errors in your original code.  I updated my answer to (hopefully) fix those.

Comment: thank you again, I updated my question with the entire code. I tryed your edited code but still the same errors, I don't know wyy :-(

Comment: Could may be help: the {ldelim} and {rdelim} are not in purple color when inside of the script but they are when outside. May be that's the reason why I hgave those errors.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved the problem by using quotes.

Comment: I test it - it works fine - except there was '/' missing in closing {/strip}.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using json_encode, like this:

```
$names = array();
foreach($result in $results)
    $names = $result['firstname']
$smarty->assign("names",json_encode($names));
```

and then later in js:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var availableTags = {/literal}{$names}{literal}; //array is pulled out from smarty
    $("#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<h1>Create Backend Users</h1>



<script>{literal}
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        {/literal}{foreach name=things from=$ufl item=uflItem}
            "{$uflItem['firstname']}"{if $smarty.foreach.things.last != true} ,{/if}
    {/foreach}{literal}
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});{/literal}
</script>


<div class="demo">
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="tags">Tags: </label>
<input id="tags">
</div>
```

you have to put literal around the curly's of js otherwise smarty is going to die

Comment: Thank you EaterOfCorpses, As I said to Alex, I am trying to use this code in a .tpl file and When I am trying to use your example, I am getting some errors.

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Syntax error on tokens, delete these 
  tokens

Comment: It's like there is something missing and the code is not recogniwed as is.

Comment: and if you replace $uflItem['firstname'] by $uflItem.firstname ?

Comment: Yes, the smarty part shuld be right. I updated my question with the complete code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved the problem by using quotes.

Comment: Oups, this is not worjking. In fact, I am using one of the earlyest smarty. May be that's the problem.

Comment: I think it is, we use smarty 2 and thats stable enough to do that

Comment: And with an older smarty, this can't be used?

Comment: since there is no documentation for 1 I dont know, but why should you use smarty 1?

Comment: Because there is some old code which is used and works with smarty 1 and I can't take the risk to reprogramm eveerything.

Comment: okay. that explains the situation, but I totally dont have anny experience with Smarty 1. the `{php}` tag saved me most times ;)

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine, the only problem that I see without running it is in javascript.
Try something like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
        {foreach from=$ufl key=index item=uflItem}
            '<tr>\
                <td>{$uflItem['firstname']}</td>\
            </tr>'{if isset($ufl[$index+1])},{/if}
    {/foreach}
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
```

By the way, since Smarty 3 **{literal}** tag is not required.

Comment: Thank you, I am using one of the earlyest smarty.